# Transition on search box not working

Tags: css, transition

I'm trying to expand the width of the search box when focus. It works fine but the transition is not working. Someone please put some light on it, what is wrong in these code. Couldn't figure it out.

```
//css file
// class name of div(.searchBox)
.searchBox {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s easy-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s easy-in-out;
  transition: all 2s easy-in-out;
}

// class name of input box
.search {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

/*
input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
*/

.searchBox form .search:focus {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #444;
}
```

the code look like these after some changes (unfortunately transition is not working)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like you miss the width in the transition. `-webkit-transition: width 2s easy-in-out;`

Comment: show your html as well

Comment: you are suppose to set your transition to your .search as you are going to change the width of your .search input alone. And you must mention it's start width.

Answer (score 4):

Try This,

```css
.searchBox {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.search {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.searchBox .search:focus {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchBox">
<input type="text" placeholder="search" class="search">
</div>
```

Comment: Please check the snippet, Its working. And Check spelling its not `easy-in-out` .. its `ease`.. `ease-in-out`

Comment: Damn on my eye. Thanks, it works, it was on spelling. U just save the day.

Comment: @ZulfikarAli consider accepting the answer if its solved your problem.